# Accessing a Python instance var from that class

Tags: python, instance-variables

I want to access an instance var from a class outside the `__init__`, but I'm getting stuck!

```
 import sys

class Borg(object):
    __shared_state = {}
    def __init__(self, nombre):
        self.__dict__ = self.__shared_state
        self.nombre = nombre 

        print 'my instance vr::', self.nombre

        # panga = 'pangas'  

    panga = 'pangas'


    print 'te copio con  ' 


    print panga

    #print self.nombre


pingus = Borg('varString')


print pingus.nombre
```

If I uncomment `print self.nombre`, I get that "`self.nombre` is not recognized"?

How do I access this var?

Comment: Your indentation appears to be messed up, because you're executing print statements inside a class definition. (and the indentation of `import sys` is wrong, too.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may work better. You should encapsulate that code in a method, like:

```
import sys

class Borg(object):
    __shared_state = {}
    def __init__(self, nombre):
        self.__dict__ = self.__shared_state
        self.nombre = nombre 

    def instance_method_1(self):
        print 'my instance vr::', self.nombre
        panga = 'pangas'
        print 'te copio con  ' 
        print panga
        print self.nombre


pingus = Borg('varString')


print pingus.nombre
pingus.instance_method_1()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't have free standing code in a python class.
You could access self.nombre from another method.

```
  def foo(self):
     print self.nombre
```

Comment: Well, you *can* have free-standing code in a Python class, but it will be executed when the class is defined, not when it is instantiated. At this point, `self` is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

When you are calling

```
print self.nombre
```

The object is not constructed yet (there is no instance of Borg when that statement is evaluated) so there is no self nor nombre. If you want to access nombre you first need to construct the object:

```
pingus  = Borg("varString")
```

and then access nombre:

```
print pingus.nombre
```